# Load balancing between two (or more) GRE tunnels

Tags: networking, routing, load-balancing, gre

I have a hosted service (think zScaler™) that is having me send my traffic to it via GRE tunnels.  I am given two appliances and want to load balance my traffic between the two tunnels.

I could always statically carve out the network but I would rather not do that.

My proposed solution is that I could create two equal cost routes between the two tunnels but wouldn't this balance on a per-packet basis.  Therefore some of the stream would go through one tunnel and some through another.  I want to avoid this since it makes troubleshooting difficult, will cause issues with the appliances tracking connections, and will likely caues issues with SSL inspection.

Is there a way, either appliance based or otherwise (I own the security equipment and can stand a load balancer up in front of it) to balance GRE tunnels based on the source IP of the originating client?  Therefore client X always goes through GRE tunnel A and client Y goes through GRE tunnel B.

My networking equipment is standard Cisco L3 Switches and ASAs.

Answer (score 0):

Using packet based equal cost balancing does not work with GRE as it will introduce reordering in the packet streams and break them. You seem to actually want a conntrack-based multipath routing which can be easily configured on any linux-based router/firewall. Multipath routing based on IP addresses is even simpler in configuration.